# SELECT from dynamic table by FK

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an object structure in C# which I'm persisting to SQL Server 2008 in a pattern similar to what is described [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/implementing-table-inheritance-in-sql-server). Basically I have some states, which different properties. There is a main State table which has an Id which is FK on the subtype tables, see attached image (there is a large number of states in the implementation).

Now, I'd like to get the properties of a given state (known Id). For instance, say Id 5 denotes an Active state, I'd like to get the values of prop1 and prop2 in the diagram.

The only way I can come up with is joining *all* the state tables (knowing that I will only get a match from one). Is there a better way of accomplishing this?

[image: Database tables]

Comment: There's no magic way - outside of dynamic SQL, every table that's going to be involved in the query has to be explicitly named.

Comment: When you insert the data into the Active/Published child table(s), can you update the State table, setting a new column to identify which sub-table the data is on, and then your first query is to retrieve the State data, and based on this new column, you choose between the queries - one just involving Active OR one just involving Published.